# Unable to call same class twice in testng XML

Tags: selenium, testng

Unable to call same class twice in Testng xml. See below example for reference. We have designed a component based approach which requires some methods to be called again. When I try this approach am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependency" error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="suite name">
    <Listeners>
        <Listener class-name="TestListeners.class" />
    </Listeners>
    <test name="SampleTest" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassOne">
                <methods>
                    <include name="methodone" />
                    <include name="methodtwo" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="ClassTwo">
                <methods>
                    <include name="clickPODSubsystem" />
                    <include name="clickWorkWithCustomerAccountsLinks" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="ClassOne">
                <methods>
                    <include name="methodthree" />
                    <include name="methodfour" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: this method has to be tests, and not some method which does configurations. if you have to do some cleanup activity use `@AfterXXX` and `@BeforeXXX` annotations.

Comment: I don't think problem is with cleanup's, because execution doesn't even start and exits with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependency" error